# log file gets created on WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.0.0 but logs are not written to it

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic, logfile

I am deploying application ear which has log4j jar in its lib folder. I am placing log4j.properties in folder /opt/beavas/vn_home which i read using environment variable.

I initialize log4j as follows

```
Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
inputStream = new FileInputStream("path to log4j.properties");
log4jProperties.load(inputStream);
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
```

and then I use

```
    Logger.getLogger(clazz).log(LoggerUtilities.class.getName(), level, msg, t);
```

where clazz is class name which I send from my application, LoggerUtilities is common class where logger is initialized.

```
level- log level, msg- log meesage, t- Throwable object is any.
```

my log4j.properties file is as follows

```
    log4j.appender.vaservices=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.vaservices.file=/opt/beavas/logs/vas_new.log
    log4j.appender.vaservices.MaxFileSize=100MB
    log4j.appender.vaservices.MaxBackupIndex=100
    log4j.appender.vaservices.append=true
    log4j.appender.vaservices.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.vaservices.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}|%-5p|%L|%t|%c|%-6m %n


    log4j.logger.com.tieto.vn.vas = DEBUG, vaservices
    log4j.logger.com.tieto.tix.core = DEBUG, vaservices
    log4j.logger.com.tieto.tix.imaging = DEBUG, vaservices
```

File vas_new.log getting create when application is updated but not logs written to it. How it could be fixed?

Comment: you haven't defined root logger.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line in log4j.properties as below:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, vaservices
```

Comment: I did not add rootLogger. I deleted ear and redeployed. Initially I was just updating. Now logs coming.  Now again logs stopped working for one application. 
So now I am thinking to add root logger and check. What could be an issue?

Comment: you just defined logging for certain packages.

Comment: Yes those packages are application specific. For other applications has different log4j properties file with different packages

Comment: My logs are working now. I do not know what made it work. As suggested by you I added log4j.rootLogger for every application log4j.properties

Comment: Yes root logger is as name suggest root at the top of every logger.